# Skip multiple groups in Codeception

Tags: php, codeception

How do you skip multiple groups in codeception? Something like:

```
--skip-group wip someFeature
```

I intend to skip Scenarios with `@wip` and `@someFeature`

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to repeat `--skip-group`, so your command would look like this `codecept run --skip-group wip --skip-group someFeature`

Use shortcut `-x` instead of `--skip-group` to make command shorter.